# Wordpress search results multiple loops by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a piece of code that allows me to have two separate loops so I can display search results in two different categories, which is great because they are also styled different.

I would like help amending this code below to include showing a 'no results found' message for each loop and add pagination for the second 'blog' category only, the top one 'shop' should show a max of 6 results.

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
        <?php
            $s = get_search_query();
        ?>
<div class="search">
    <div class="categoryThumbs">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h3>
    <?php endif;?>
        <?php query_posts("s='$s'&category_name=shop"); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $blogResults=0; ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    $blogResults++;
                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
                <h4><?php echo $blogResults; ?> Results in Shop</h4>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="films">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php query_posts("s='$s'&category_name=blog"); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $blogResults=0; ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                    $blogResults++;
                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
                <h4><?php echo $blogResults; ?> Results in Blog</h4>
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="films">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="search">
<div class="categoryThumbs">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <h3><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h3>
<?php endif;?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <h4><?php echo wp_count_posts(); ?> Results in Shop</h4>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
              $taxonomy = 'category';
              $queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
              $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $queried_term, $taxonomy );
              $termName =  $term->name;
              if($termName == 'shop'):
             ?>
            <div class="films">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                </div>
                <h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else: 
              // others code for blog
             endif; endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif;?>

<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```